# CRUD/FLS checks on Dynamic SOQL - Needed for WHERE clause?

Tags: apex, security-review, fls

For the AppExchange Security Review, do we need to check FLS on a Dynamic SOQL WHERE clause as well?

Ex: If Contact.My_Custom_Field__c is not visible to the logged in user, then the following SOQL would be a violation of FLS?

```
SELECT Id FROM Contact WHERE My_Custom_Field__c = 'Oh really'
```

Comment: Keeping this question around for the discussion below with @PhilW. I think the community will benefit from the back and forth below.

Answer (score -2):

From Robert Sussland's answer [here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/145561/55891), sounds like you need to check permissions everywhere:

> Once you have the list of fields you need to check perms for, it doesn't matter whether they are used in WHERE clauses or directly accessed -- you need to make sure that the perms are checked.

Comment: Close as duplicate then?

Comment: I entirely disagree with this answer btw. Security is about restricting a user's access to data (so they can't see it or edit it as appropriate. It is NOT about what data the application itself can use on behalf of a user.

Comment: @PhilW I appreciate you honesty here. 1) Is that how FLS operates?  I, the running user, could have SOQL queries running in the backend using WHERE clauses on fields FLS says they can't see?

2) My question was more specific with regard to the Security Review.

Comment: I work for an ISV. We have to pass the security review to keep the app on App Exchange. We DO apply CRUD/FLS generally, but not against every field in every query (though always for fields we "return to the user"). We DO comment the SOQL to explain why fields are not checked so the Salesforce Security Review Team can't argue. We annotate every line that Checkmarx would extract at the bottom of a "stack trace" as part of a scan and mark it with a CRUD/FLS False Positive comment (typically the first line of the static SOQL or the "Database.query" call).

Comment: We do the same for DML operations - if we must update a field without FLS checks, for example, the assignment to that field is marked with the trailing CRUD/FLS False Positive comment and we also mark the DML operation statement itself. Again this ensures that the Checkmarx report already explains why we don't apply the check. Thus the output of Checkmarx becomes our "CRUD/FLS False Positives" documentation.

Comment: Excellect explanations - this is really helpful

Comment: @PhilW Just had technical security review hours, and they said that it's policy to always perform FLS checks even on where clause fields (even though he admitted that if the where clause isn't affected by user input, then there's less of an issue here).

Comment: @BrianMiller, as long as you have a reason NOT to check FLS that you communicate to the Salesforce security team as part of your review and that makes sense to them then you don't have to do it. As I said, we have numerous utilities and background processes that require full data access irrespective of execution context user and they understand and allow this with explanations.